# Mule ESB 3.3 Exception Strategies & Rollback baffling behaviour

Tags: transactions, esb, mule, rollback

**Setup:**
Tabe: `CREATE TABLE test (id int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, name varchar(25));`

**Basic test flow:**

[image]

**Preconditions:**  The database already has a record with id=2 (to force SqlException)

**Case 1:**

Whe basic flow is invoked as is, the second insert fails due to primary key violation, and the first insert gets rolled back. Seems like a reasonable default behaviour.

**Case 2:**

Modify base flow by adding a **Rollback Exception Strategy** and add a logger inside the exception strategy to print something when it gets called.
When flow is invoked, the second insert fails due to primary key violation, and the first insert gets rolled back **but** the RollbackExceptionStrategy never gets called!
Hardly what anyone would expect.

So the question here is: Why doesn't the rollback exception strategy gets called and what I need to do to get it called?

**Case 3:**

Modify base flow by adding a **Catch Exception Strategy** and add a logger inside the exception strategy to print something when it gets called.
When flow is invoked, the second insert fails due to primary key violation.  This time, the exception strategy is called but now the transaction was **not** rolled back.

The question here is: Why is the transaction not being rolled back and how to force a rollback inside an exception strategy different from a rollback strategy?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

---

**Edit1**: Here is the complete xml for the flow (only basic case):

```
<mule>
    <spring:beans>
        <spring:bean id="dataSource" name="dataSource" class="org.enhydra.jdbc.standard.StandardDataSource" destroy-method="shutdown">
            <spring:property name="driverName" value="org.h2.Driver" />
            <spring:property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/mule" />
            <spring:property name="user" value="sa" />
            <spring:property name="password">
                <spring:value></spring:value>
            </spring:property>
        </spring:bean>

        <spring:bean id="transactionFactory" name="transactionFactory" class="org.mule.transport.jdbc.JdbcTransactionFactory" />

    </spring:beans>

    <jdbc:connector name="dbConnector" dataSource-ref="dataSource" validateConnections="true" queryTimeout="-1" pollingFrequency="0" doc:name="Database" />

    <flow name="TriggerFlow" doc:name="TriggerFlow">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP" />
        <vm:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" path="txFlow" doc:name="VM" />
    </flow>

    <flow name="TxFlow" doc:name="case1Flow">
        <vm:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" path="txFlow" doc:name="case1">
            <custom-transaction factory-ref="transactionFactory" action="ALWAYS_BEGIN" timeout="10" />
        </vm:inbound-endpoint>
        <jdbc:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" queryKey="insert" queryTimeout="-1" connector-ref="dbConnector" doc:name="insert into test values (1, 'Test 1')">
            <jdbc:transaction action="ALWAYS_JOIN" />
            <jdbc:query key="insert" value="insert into test values (1, 'Test 1')" />
        </jdbc:outbound-endpoint>
        <jdbc:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" queryKey="insert2" queryTimeout="-1" connector-ref="dbConnector" doc:name="insert into test values (2, 'Test 2')">
            <jdbc:transaction action="ALWAYS_JOIN" />
            <jdbc:query key="insert2" value="insert into test values (2, 'Test 2')" />
        </jdbc:outbound-endpoint>
    </flow>

</mule>
```

---

**Edit2**: As it turns out, case 2 in isolation works, but it doesn't work in a more complex flow for example:

```
<mule>
    <spring:beans>
        <spring:bean id="dataSource" name="dataSource" class="org.enhydra.jdbc.standard.StandardDataSource" destroy-method="shutdown">
            <spring:property name="driverName" value="org.h2.Driver" />
            <spring:property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/mule" />
            <spring:property name="user" value="sa" />
            <spring:property name="password">
                <spring:value></spring:value>
            </spring:property>
        </spring:bean>

        <spring:bean id="transactionFactory" name="transactionFactory" class="org.mule.transport.jdbc.JdbcTransactionFactory" />

    </spring:beans>

    <jdbc:connector name="dbConnector" dataSource-ref="dataSource" validateConnections="true" queryTimeout="-1" pollingFrequency="0" doc:name="Database" />

    <flow name="TriggerTxFlow" doc:name="TriggerTxFlow">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP" />
        <set-variable variableName="flow" value="#[message.inboundProperties['http.query.params']['flow']]" doc:name="Variable"/>
        <vm:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" path="#[flow]" doc:name="VM" />
    </flow>

    <flow name="case1Flow" doc:name="case1Flow">
        <vm:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" path="case1" doc:name="case1">
            <custom-transaction factory-ref="transactionFactory" action="ALWAYS_BEGIN" timeout="10" />
        </vm:inbound-endpoint>
        <jdbc:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" queryKey="insert" queryTimeout="-1" connector-ref="dbConnector" doc:name="insert into test values (1, 'Test 1')">
            <jdbc:transaction action="ALWAYS_JOIN" />
            <jdbc:query key="insert" value="insert into test values (1, 'Test 1')" />
        </jdbc:outbound-endpoint>
        <jdbc:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" queryKey="insert2" queryTimeout="-1" connector-ref="dbConnector" doc:name="insert into test values (2, 'Test 2')">
            <jdbc:transaction action="ALWAYS_JOIN" />
            <jdbc:query key="insert2" value="insert into test values (2, 'Test 2')" />
        </jdbc:outbound-endpoint>
    </flow>

    <flow name="case2Flow" doc:name="case2Flow">
        <vm:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" path="case2" doc:name="case2">
            <custom-transaction factory-ref="transactionFactory" action="ALWAYS_BEGIN" timeout="10" />
        </vm:inbound-endpoint>
        <jdbc:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" queryKey="insert" queryTimeout="-1" connector-ref="dbConnector" doc:name="Database">
            <jdbc:transaction action="ALWAYS_JOIN" />
            <jdbc:query key="insert" value="insert into test values (1, 'Test 1')" />
        </jdbc:outbound-endpoint>
        <jdbc:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" queryKey="insert2" queryTimeout="-1" connector-ref="dbConnector" doc:name="Database">
            <jdbc:transaction action="ALWAYS_JOIN" />
            <jdbc:query key="insert2" value="insert into test values (2, 'Test 2')" />
        </jdbc:outbound-endpoint>
        <rollback-exception-strategy doc:name="Rollback Exception Strategy" enableNotifications="false" maxRedeliveryAttempts="0">
            <on-redelivery-attempts-exceeded doc:name="Redelivery exhausted">
                <logger message="========= Inside Exception Strategy =========" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
            </on-redelivery-attempts-exceeded>
        </rollback-exception-strategy>
    </flow>

    <flow name="case3Flow" doc:name="case3Flow">
        <vm:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" path="case3" doc:name="VM">
            <custom-transaction factory-ref="transactionFactory" action="ALWAYS_BEGIN" timeout="10" />
        </vm:inbound-endpoint>
        <jdbc:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" queryKey="insert" queryTimeout="-1" connector-ref="dbConnector" doc:name="Database">
            <jdbc:transaction action="ALWAYS_JOIN" />
            <jdbc:query key="insert" value="insert into test values (1, 'Test 1')" />
        </jdbc:outbound-endpoint>
        <jdbc:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" queryKey="insert2" queryTimeout="-1" connector-ref="dbConnector" doc:name="Database">
            <jdbc:transaction action="ALWAYS_JOIN" />
            <jdbc:query key="insert2" value="insert into test values (2, 'Test 2')" />
        </jdbc:outbound-endpoint>
        <catch-exception-strategy doc:name="Catch Exception Strategy">
            <logger message="========= Inside Exception Strategy =========" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        </catch-exception-strategy>
    </flow>

</mule>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Case 1**: Yay!

**Case 2**:

*Why doesn't the rollback exception strategy gets called and what I need to do to get it called?*

According to the [doc](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Rollback+Exception+Strategy) the strategy should be called. It is maybe a configuration issue on your side because if I add:

```
<rollback-exception-strategy>
    <logger message="---> In Rollback exception strategy!!!" />
</rollback-exception-strategy>
```

to "TxFlow" I can see the text being logged in the console.

**Case 3**:

*Why is the transaction not being rolled back?*

That is the main purpose of the *Catch Exception Strategy*, from the [doc](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Catch+Exception+Strategy):

> ensure that a transaction processed by the flow will not be rolled back when an error occurs (i.e. The transaction is never “rolled back” to reattempt processing; Mule commits the transaction.)

*How to force a rollback inside an exception strategy different from a rollback strategy*

I don't think you can. You can try throwing an exception from within the strategy but I'm afraid the transaction is already committed at that time.

Comment: I just added the XML of the flow for the basic case.  It is not an in-memory db but it is incredibly easy to set up. Just fire h2 db as this: java -cp  h2-1.3.170.jar org.h2.tools.Server  (http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/com/h2database/h2/1.3.170/h2-1.3.170.jar).

Comment: This is awesome, I'm looking into it.

Comment: Thanks David, you are right. Case 2 in isolation works, but in a more complex flow it doesn't.  I just added the actual flow I was using for testing.  It includes the 3 cases.  You invoke each passing parameters to the trigger flow as this:  http://localhost:8081/?flow=case2

Comment: Wait, you use `on-redelivery-attempts-exceeded` in `rollback-exception-strategy`: you never mentioned that. Also you use a JDBC transaction factory on an inbound VM endpoint. Don't you want instead an XA transaction between VM and JDBC so the VM delivery gets rolled-back too, thus leading to redeliveries thus potentially triggering `on-redelivery-attempts-exceeded`.

Comment: Geez, I didn't notice that the logger got into the <on-redelivery-attempts-exceeded> instead of the body of the <rollback-exception-strategy> tag when I dragged-n-dropped it in the Mule Studio! David, how can I pay you? You anwser every mule question.  Really you should start charging me.

Comment: ROFL Don't tempt me :D But feel free to engage me through my consulting business (see my profile) if you end-up having hairy issues to tackle!

Answer (score 0):

Try this to force a rollback inside an ES :

```
<custom-exception-strategy class="..." >
    <rollback-transaction exception-pattern="*"/>
</custom-exception-strategy>
```